# Matlab | How to load/use files with consecutive names (abc1, abc2, abc3) and then pass on to the next series (cba1, cba2, cba3)?

Tags: matlab

I have a folder containing a series of data with file names like this:
abc1
abc2
abc3
bca1
bca2
bca3
bca4
bca5
cba1
... etc

My goal is to load all the relevant files for each file name, so all the "abc" files, and plot them in one graph. Then move on to the next file name, and do the same, and so forth. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I currently have to load and run through all the files, grab the data in them and get their name (without the .mat extension) to be able to save the graph with the same filename.

```
dirName = 'C:\DataDirectory';
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.mat') ); 
files = {files.name}'; 
data = cell(numel(files),1); 
for i=1:numel(files)
    fname = fullfile(dirName,files{i});
    disp(fname);
    files{i} = files{i}(1:length(files{i})-4);
    disp(files{i});
    [Rest of script]
end
```

Comment: you have the right method, just use something like `dir('abc*.mat');` the parameter in `dir` works like a regex. BTW this means any .mat file that start with abc. You can also do `dir('*abc.mat')`; which means any .mat file that ends with abc; or `dir('*abc*.mat')` which means any .mat file that contains abc in the middle etc.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's a decent solution. I could just split the loop as it is now into smaller loops for each file name, maybe.

Comment: Do you know all prefixes `abc`, `bca`, ..., or do you need to find them dynamically in the program?

Comment: I know all of them, but they COULD vary depending on which measurements we've executed. Ideally it would run through the folder, find the prefixes and run only on the present ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already found out about the cool features of `dir`, and have a cell array `files`, which contains all file names, e.g.

```
files = 
    '37abc1.mat'
    '37abc2.mat'
    '50bca1.mat'
    '50bca2.mat'
    '1cba1.mat'
    '1cba2.mat'
```

The main task now is to find all prefixes, `37abc`, `50bca`, `1cba`, ... which are present in `files`. This can be done using a regular expression ([regexp](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)). The Regexp Pattern can look like this:

```
'([\d]*[\D]*)[\d]*.mat'
```

i.e. take any number of numbers (`[\d]*`), then any number of non-numeric characters (`[\D]*`) and *keep those* (by putting that in brackets). Next, there will be any number of numeric characters (`[\d]*`), followed by the text `.mat`.
We call the [`regexp`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) function  with that pattern:

```
pre = regexp(files,'([\d]*[\D]*)[\d]*.mat','tokens');
```

resulting in a cell array (one cell for each entry in `files`), where each cell contains another cell array with the prefix of that file. To convert this to a simple not-nested cell array, we call

```
pre = [pre{:}];
pre = [pre{:}];
```

resulting in

```
pre = 
    '37abc'    '37abc'    '50bca'    '50bca'    '1cba'    '1cba'
```

To remove duplicate entries, we use the [`unique`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function:

```
pre = unique(pre);
pre = 
    '37abc'    '50bca'    '1cba'
```

which leaves us with all prefixes, that are present. Now you can loop through each of these prefixes and apply your stuff. Everything put together is:

```
% Find all files
dirName = 'C:\DataDirectory';
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.mat') ); 
files = {files.name}'; 

% Find unique prefixes
pre = regexp(files,'([\d]*[\D]*)[\d]*.mat','tokens');
pre = [pre{:}]; pre = [pre{:}];
pre = unique(pre);

% Loop through prefixes
for ii=1:numel(pre)
    % Get files with this prefix
    curFiles = dir(fullfile(dirName,[pre{ii},'*.mat']));
    curFiles = {curFiles.name}';

    % Loop through all files with this prefix
    for jj=1:numel(curFiles)
        % Here the magic happens
    end
end
```

Comment: In your example, curFiles fails to load anything for me. The actual file names are like this "50abc1" "50abc2" "50abc3" etc. Could it be trying to find files with the prefix "abc" but there are none because the prefix is actually "50abc" ?

The prefix listing works like a charm, by the way.

Comment: Yes, the regexp only works for: `<not-numbers><numbers>.mat`. I changed it to work for `<numbers><not-numbers><numbers>.mat`, where `<numbers><not-numbers>` is interpreted as prefix. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I found this solution:

```
file = dir('*.mat')
matching = regexp({file.name}, '^[a-zA-Z_]+[0-9]+\.mat$', 'match', 'once'); %// Match once on file name, must be a series of A-Z a-z chars followed by numbers.
matching = matching(~cellfun('isempty', matching));
str = unique(regexp(matching, '^[a-zA-Z_]*', 'match', 'once'));
str = str(~cellfun('isempty', str));
group = cell(size(str));

for is = 1:length(str)
    ismatch = strncmp(str{is}, matching, length(str{is}));
    group{is} = matching(ismatch);
end
```

Answer came from this source: [Matlab Central](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/276731)